# Decode byte to bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've written code to code my bitmap to byte and I can't decode it and save "getImage" as byte.

```
public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView noteImage) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)noteImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.save_note){

            Note note = new Note(noteTitle.getText().toString(),
                    noteContent.getText().toString(),
                    noteTPhone.getText().toString(),
                    noteClient.getText().toString(),
                    noteAge.getText().toString(),
                    todaysDate,currentTime,
            imageViewToByte(noteImage));




            NoteDatabase db = new NoteDatabase(this);
            db.addNote(note);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goToMain();
        }
```

Decode attepmt

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, blob);
        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] image  = blob.toByteArray();


        contentDetails.setText(note.getContent());
        titleDetails.setText(note.getTitle());
        phoneDetails.setText(note.getPhone());
        clientDetails.setText(note.getClient());
        ageDetails.setText(note.getAge());
        imageDetails.setImageBitmap(note.getImage(zdjecie));
```

Finally it's not working.. I appreciate any help

Comment: It's perhaps throwing an error in `LogCat`?

Comment: No, application just crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Note model class consists of image data as a byte array, and for setting bitmap to image view just call getImageFromByte() method like below.

```
imageDetails.setImageBitmap(getImageFromByte(note.getImage()));
```

After the getImageFromByte() like this below for decode a byte array to bitmap and returned the bitmap for image view.

```
private Bitmap getImageFromByte(byte[] bytes){
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
```

That's is the byte array converts to Bitmap. Enjoy, Thanks.

Comment: please let me know what is the issue? and what function you need in that?